# vue create ошибка "не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом."

Tags: vue-cli, vue3

При создании проекта почему то видимо
он обращается в дирректорию:\Desktop\node_modules.bin
хотя в Path добавлял путь: program files\nodejs; appdada\npm...
Обучение встало уже на месяц изза этого!((

```
✨  Creating project in C:\Users\Bolat & Ylia\Desktop\vue-cli.
⚙️  Installing CLI plugins. This might take a while...

"Ylia\Desktop\node_modules\.bin\" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@vue%2fcli-plugin-babel failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND proxy.example.com
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the   
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Bolat & Ylia\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-06-09T09_19_59_366Z-debug.log
 ERROR  command failed: npm install --loglevel error --legacy-peer-deps
```

node -v 16.2.0

npm -v 7.14.0

vue -V 4.5.13

windows 10

очень прошу помочь!!!

Answer (score 0):

Судя по ошибке, проблема в пути к директории проекта. Попробуйте обернуть путь в кавычки:

`C:\Users\Bolat & Ylia\Desktop\vue-cli` -> `"C:\Users\Bolat & Ylia\Desktop\vue-cli"`

Или переименуйте `"Bolat & Ylia"` на имя без пробелов.

Comment: А вот такой текст ни на что не намекает? `reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND proxy.example.co`? Я просто хз. Ниже идёт разговор о сетевых недоразумениях